# webview re-wraps text using on-screen zoom controls and pinch-zoom-out, but not pinch-zoom-in

Tags: android, webview

Something odd happening here...

I've got a WebView in my app and I'm using

```
getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

On a API level 10 device, when I use the built-in controls (the + and -) to zoom in/out, the text automatically re-wraps after zooming, so that it all still fits on the screen.  Likewise, if I pinch-zoom-out (make the text smaller), it automatically re-wraps.  But if I pinch-zoom-in, the text gets bigger, but it doesn't re-wrap.  Interestingly, a double-tap at this point will re-wrap the text.

What's happening inside the implementation of the built-in zoom-in control and the double-tap event processing that's not happening in the pinch-zoom-in processing, and can I make it happen programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, added:

```
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

this should do the job - stops the rewrapping thingy :\

Comment: did you post this in the right place?  It doesn't seem related to the question.

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't have the desired effect for me.  To clarify, what I want is to pinch-zoom-in (spread fingers apart, causing text to get bigger), and after lifting fingers from the screen, the text should automatically rewrap so that the line breaks are appropriate for the screen size, requiring no horizontal scrolling to read the text.

Comment: hmmm... did you try to setLoadWithOverviewMode true and setUseWideViewPort false?